# Can Hibernate map subset of columns into an internal sub Pojo

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following Pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
class User {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age;

   private long lastVisited;
   private long lastPlayed;
   private long lastPayed;

   ...
}
```

I would like somehow if possible to map the Pojo like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
class User {
   @Id
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age;

   @Embedded
   private UserStatistics statistics;

   ...
}

@Embeddable
class UserStatistics {   
   private long lastVisited;
   private long lastPlayed;
   private long lastPayed;
}
```

*BUT*, I DON'T want to move the statistics columns into a new 
`USER_STATISTICS` table and do `@OneToOne` mapping.

Is there a Hibernate trick I can use here?
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with that? doesn't this solution work?

Comment: This solution is my ideal one and not implemented, but if I want it like this I probably need to adjust my DB schema and create a new table which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is already enough, Hibernate does not require you to define fields for all columns in your table. It's rather the other way around - all non-transient fields should be reflected as columns in the corresponding table either using name defined in `@Column` annotation or generated using a naming convention used in hibernate configuration.

The example you presented is sufficient and will work, but I wouldn't recommend it as you can have two entities mapping single row at the same time.

Comment: I didn't use any `@Column` annotation to simplify my example, but in my real code - how would I annotate `statistics` ?

Comment: @Shvalb I thought you want to have two entities, not an embedded one

Comment: It's actually 2 different Pojos but mapped to the same table. The question is how to annotate it to make it work.

Comment: @Shvalb the same way you did with the first entity, but you need to add an `@Id`

Comment: perhaps I need to use `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` ?

Comment: You posted two questions on the same topic, I answered both of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202656/discussion-between-shvalb-and-andronicus).